# In SQL how can I use one query to set variables to conduct additional queries (Access Control People Proximity COVID-19)

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to create a report for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) where a user can provide an employees name and date ranges and it will return not only that employees door activity between those dates, but also other employees within a time range before and after them.  This is being used to track potential cases and see who else might have come in contact withe that person.  I can get the two separate pieces working, but I can't figure out a way to iterate through the results.

Variables to be set by users:

```
@Person varchar(max)
@Begin datetime2
@End datetime2
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
FROM DoorJournal
WHERE Person like @Person
AND Time BETWEEN @Begin AND @End
```

From Query 1, I want to pull in the door and time of the person's access and pass it through to the next query

```
@Door varchar(max) 
@Entry datetime2
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
FROM DoorJournal
WHERE Door like @Door
AND Time BETWEEN (DateAdd(minute,-2,@Entry) AND (DateAdd(minute,15,@Entry)
```

I then want to union those results together so we end up with a view like this

```
Admitted     Time    Door    Person
Yes          9:05    Door 1  Person 1
Yes          9:06    Door 1  Person 2
Yes          9:07    Door 1  Query 1 Person
Yes          9:10    Door 1  Person 3
Yes          10:15   Door 2  Person 5
Yes          10:16   Door 2  Query 1 Person
Yes          10:21   Door 2  Person 4
```

The query will be run against one person per time, but each door the person goes through and the time before and after they go through the door should be included so there will be multiple values for door and the times.

I'm not sure how to pass the information from the one query to the other.  I've tried with some subqueries, but never got anything to function as expected.

```
SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
FROM (SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
FROM DoorJournal
WHERE Person like @Person
AND Time BETWEEN @Begin AND @End) AS P
WHERE Door IN (P.Door)
AND Time BETWEEN (DateAdd(minute,-2,P.Time) AND (DateAdd(minute,15,P.Time)
```

Adding solution based on Alan's suggestion:

```
Select Time, Door
INTO #specific
WHERE Person like @Person
AND Time BETWEEN @Begin AND @End

SELECT Admitted,
Time,
D.Person,
Door
FROM DoorJournal D
INNER JOIN #specific s ON D.Person = S.Person
WHERE D.Door = S.Door
AND D.Time BETWEEN (DateAdd(minute,-2,S.Time) AND (DateAdd(minute,15,S.Time)
```

Comment: `WHERE (person  like ...) OR (door ....)`

Comment: If this comment is for the first Where (inside the subquery) then I don't know what doors are going to be present until the query executes.  If it is for the second Where clause, then I don't get anyone else because I only get the person defined in the first where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it. I've done this without testing so can't guarantee that's it's 100% correct and I don't have time to create sample data...

If this is incorrect and you can't work it out, then post some sample data and I'll update the answer.

```
-- Get specified persons door activity
-- dump it into a temp table
SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
INTO #specific
FROM DoorJournal
WHERE Person = @Person
AND Time BETWEEN @Begin AND @End

-- get activity from all people at the same doors, extending the time range
-- we include the original person here so we only have to query this one table at the end.
SELECT Admitted,
Time,
Person,
Door
INTO #others
FROM DoorJournal dj
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Door from #specific) s ON dj.Door = d.Door
WHERE Time BETWEEN DateAdd(minute,-2,@Entry) AND DateAdd(minute,15,@Entry)

-- Join the 2 together and get the results
SELECT 
    ot.*
    FROM #specific sp 
        JOIN #others ot ON sp.Door = ot.Door
    ORDER BY ot.Time, ot.Door, ot.Person
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the @Person will only ever return one person because we will be using their unique identifier.  Your method would absolutely work, but there are hundreds of doors so there would be a lot of unneeded information in the others table that would really slow down the performance.

Comment: Ok I'll modify the answerin the morning it's 00:50 here now

Comment: The modified code now only queries a single person and also the second table is filtered down to just the doors used by the first person..

Comment: I modified it further to only use 1 temporary table.  This got me on the right path.